# How to find which file is under heavy use/IO

Tags: resources, monitoring, linux

Application on the Linux server is using several large files of 10-20 GB in size. It is constantly writing and reading on all of them, I want to see usage details: which file is under heavy use, see bandwidth, operation count etc. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is still a duplicate of the other question with the same answer - systemtap.